# how to check the person exist in a linked list, dynamic data structure in C language?

Tags: c, data-structures, dynamic, linked-list

this are the codes from header file:

```
typedef struct Human {                  
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    struct Human *mother;
    struct Human *father;
    struct Human *next;
} Human;

void addHuman(List *list, char *name, char *surname, Human *father, Human *mother);
Human *findHuman(List *list, char *name, char *surname);
```

the following code is from the source file and it does not work:

```
void addHuman(List *list, char *name, char *surname, Human *father, Human *mother);


    // Check if the list is NULL
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("Error: List is NULL\n");
        return;
    }
    // Check if the person already exists in the list
    Human *existingHuman = findHuman(list, name, surname);
    if (existingHuman != NULL) {
    printf("Person exists already.\n");
    return;
    }

    // Create new person
    Human *new = (Human *) malloc(sizeof(Human));
    strcpy(new->name, name); //strcpy:copy strings
    strcpy(new->surname, surname);
    new->mother = mother;
    new->father = father;
```

how can I fix it?

Thanks for your help!

I tried to check if the global and local variables match.`

Comment: What *specifically* do you mean by "it does not work"?  What "global and local variables" are you referring to?

Comment: Please provide a detailed description of what makes you think "it does not work" (e.g. what you expect in contrast to what you observe) and a [mre] which demonstrates it. Because the answer to "It does not work, How can I fix it?" is "Find the bug and correct it." - notice the similar levels of helpful details?

Answer (score 1):

To check if someone (or an element) is in a linked list, you have to go through the linked list and compare each element to what you are looking for. Here's how you can do it in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> // Include the header for boolean data type

bool personExists(const char* name, const char* surname) {
    Human* current = head; // Start from the beginning of the list

    while (current != NULL) {
        // Compare the name and surname with the current element
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && strcmp(current->surname, surname) == 0) {
            return true; // Person found in the list
        }
        current = current->next; // Move to the next element
    }

    return false; // Person not found in the list
}
```

You can call this personExists function in your code to check if a person exists in the linked list:

```
if (personExists("John", "Doe")) {
    printf("Person exists in the list.\n");
} else {
    printf("Person does not exist in the list.\n");
}
```

In case the addHuman function is not working from the source file, this should work instead (Suggestions incorporated):

```
// Include necessary headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Define the Human structure
typedef struct Human {
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    struct Human* mother;
    struct Human* father;
    struct Human* next;
} Human;

// Define the List structure if not already defined
typedef struct List {
    // Define the list structure here
    // You can include a pointer to the first Human in the list, for example
    Human* head;
} List;

// Function prototypes
void addHuman(List* list, char* name, char* surname, Human* father, Human* mother);
Human* findHuman(List* list, char* name, char* surname);

// Implementation of addHuman function
void addHuman(List* list, char* name, char* surname, Human* father, Human* mother) {
    // Check if the list is NULL
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("Error: List is NULL\n");
        return;
    }

    // Check if the person already exists in the list
    Human* existingHuman = findHuman(list, name, surname);
    if (existingHuman != NULL) {
        printf("Person exists already.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Create new person
    Human* new = (Human*)malloc(sizeof(Human));
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Memory allocation failed\n");
        return;
    }

    strcpy(new->name, name);
    strcpy(new->surname, surname);
    new->mother = mother;
    new->father = father;

    // Add new person to the list
    new->next = list->head;
    list->head = new;
}

// Implementation of findHuman function (you need to define this function)

int main() {
    // Initialize your list
    List myList;
    myList.head = NULL;

    // Example usage:
    addHuman(&myList, "John", "Doe", NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also worked on a possible solution to your issue, and is similar to the initially submitted answer.  The basic premise would be to set up some type of initial "Human" structures and then read through the list as new entries are created.  Since there was no minimum code, this afforded me a bit of artistic license to provide a code set that provides food for thought.  Following is the prototype code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 50

typedef struct Human
{
    char name[SIZE];
    char surname[SIZE];
    struct Human *mother;
    struct Human *father;
    struct Human *next;
} Human;

Human * add_parent(char * first, char * last)
{
    Human * work = malloc(sizeof(Human));
    strcpy(work->name, first);
    strcpy(work->surname, last);
    work->mother = NULL;
    work->father = NULL;
    work->next   = NULL;

    return work;
}

Human * findHuman(Human *ls, char *name, char *surname)
{
    Human * work = ls;

    while(1)
    {
        if ((strcmp(work->name, name) == 0) && strcmp(work->surname, surname) == 0)
            return work;
        if (work->next == NULL)
            break;
        work = work->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void addHuman(Human *list, char *name, char *surname, Human *father, Human *mother)
{
    // Check if the list is NULL
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: List is NULL\n");
        return;
    }
    // Check if the person already exists in the list
    //Human *existingHuman = findHuman(list, name, surname);
    if (findHuman(list, name, surname) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Person exists already.\n");
        return;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if (list->next == NULL)
            break;
        list = list->next;
    }

    // Create new person
    Human *new = (Human *) malloc(sizeof(Human));
    strcpy(new->name, name); //strcpy:copy strings
    strcpy(new->surname, surname);
    new->mother = mother;
    new->father = father;
    new->next   = NULL;

    list->next = new;

    return;
}

int main()
{
    Human * Dad = NULL;
    Human * Mom = NULL;
    Human * Lst = NULL;

    char f_name[SIZE];
    char l_name[SIZE];

    Mom = add_parent("Jane", "Smith");          /* Some initial parents */
    Dad = add_parent("John", "Smith");

    Mom->next = Dad;

    printf("Mom: %s %s\n", Mom->name, Mom->surname);
    printf("Dad: %s %s\n", Mom->next->name, Mom->next->surname);

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter first name or \"quit\" to end entry: ");
        if (scanf("%s", f_name) != 1)
            break;

        if (strcmp(f_name, "quit") == 0)
            break;

        printf("Enter last name: ");
        if (scanf("%s", l_name) != 1)
            break;

        addHuman(Mom, f_name, l_name, NULL, NULL);
    }

    Lst = Mom;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("First Name: %s  Last Name: %s\n", Lst->name, Lst->surname);

        if (Lst->next == NULL)
            break;
        Lst = Lst->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Following are some points to note.

- In some manner, initial structure entries need to be created, which in this prototype, was done with an "add_parent" function.
- A simple prompt loop was added within the "main" function to allow for additional human structures to be added to the list.
- When structures were added, string comparison functions are used in the "findHuman" function.
- If allowed, the new human structure is added by first traversing the current linked list, starting at the initial (head) entry, until the "next" structure pointer is "NULL".

Following is a simple test at the terminal to illustrate the creation of an initial structure list (with a mother and a father).  This, of course could be done in a different manner, but does get an initial list in place.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Genealogy/bin/Release$ ./Genealogy 
Mom: Jane Smith
Dad: John Smith
Enter first name or "quit" to end entry: Bill
Enter last name: Smith
Enter first name or "quit" to end entry: Bill
Enter last name: Smith
Person exists already.
Enter first name or "quit" to end entry: Tom
Enter last name: Elliot
Enter first name or "quit" to end entry: quit
First Name: Jane  Last Name: Smith
First Name: John  Last Name: Smith
First Name: Bill  Last Name: Smith
First Name: Tom  Last Name: Elliot
```

Ultimately, there would need to be more polish to this prototype, but it should provide food for thought on the building of a linked list as well as the traversal of the list.  The other takeaway would be to probably delve more into some "C" tutorials as they pertain to linked lists, strings, pointers, and loops.